# Which is correct: Saint Poetic Tradition or Saintly-Poetic Tradition or Saint-Poetic Tradition?

Tags: hyphenation, compound-adjectives

Which is correct: The Saint Poetic Tradition or The Saintly-Poetic Tradition or the Saint-Poetic Tradition?

I want to write about the tradition of poets who were also saints. Which of the above is correct?

Comment: Assuming it's meaningful to write about a "tradition" of such poets, the concept might be more accurately conveyed by *The **Sainted** Poet[s] tradition* (though I imagine most if not all of them wouldn't have been beatified until long after death). I don't really think the modified form ***saintly*** works very well here, because that would often be interpreted as a metaphoric usage, whereas you intend it to be understood *literally*. Also consider *the Romantic Poet[s] tradition* (where ***poetic*** would be very unlikely).

Comment: "... poetic tradition" makes it seem like the tradition is poetic, which seems to say that the tradition is used in poetry or is written in poetry. Surely it would be better to speak of a "poet tradition", which would be a tradition of poets, or a poetry tradition.

Comment: I don't know who St Poetic is, but he sounds like a mensch.

Comment: @Phil Sweet: I don't know if there are still people who debate how many angels could dance on the head of a pin, but to me, even debating the *existence* of angels seems primitive. I've just spent a minute checking the difference between *canonization* and *beatification*, but it mostly seems to be a matter of arcane procedural differences rather than a way to distinguish "true" saints from those who are merely "blessed". (But please *don't* try to enlighten me - I really wouldn't care enough to remember even if you succeeded! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing about poets who were formal saints, "the saint-poet tradition" would express that best. The compound modifier "saint-poet" establishes that there is such a being.

However, if you're writing about poets who were generally saintly,
"the saintly-poet tradition" would best express that. Here you need the hyphenated compound modifier to distinguish the idea from a poets tradition that was in itself saintly.

A compound modifier is a sequence of modifiers of a noun that function as a single unit. It consists of two or more words (adjectives, gerunds, or nouns) of which the left-hand component modifies the right-hand one, as in "the dark-green dress": dark modifies the green that modifies dress. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound#Compound_nouns

Comment: I concur with this distinction, except for the hyphen in "saintly-poet", which I would suggest should be "saintly poet" instead.

Comment: @GregoryBenoit Except that a _saintly poet_ could be a poet whose character is considered saintly without actually having been canonised. In fact it could be applied to a living person who cannot, by definition, be made a saint.

Comment: @BoldBen "-ly" precludes hyphen; Zan700 wrote "if you're writing about poets who were generally saintly", to which I was responding; thus you have reiterated my point

Comment: @Gregory Benoit "-ly" does not preclude a hyphen if the word ending in "ly" is not an adverb. Saintly is an adjective. Other examples from grammarbook.com Correct: the friendly-looking dog
Correct: a family-owned cafe

Comment: Because it's an issue of "poets who are saints", I would lean towards "poet-saint tradition" rather than "saint-poet". But I think it's also like that English thing of ordering adjectives: it just feels better that way.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you are writing about the traditions of a group of people called the 'Saint-Poets' or 'Saint Poets' ([perhaps these people](http://www.spiritual-happiness.com/poetsaints.html) or [these people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sant_Mat)?) then it's normal to make the adjective that describes them as close to the noun as possible. In that case **just as poets have a poetic tradition, Saint-Poets have a Saint-Poetic tradition.** I would probably keep the hyphen, even if it isn't present in the noun. **You might also talk about the 'Saint Poet tradition'**. Using strings of nouns where one noun modifies the other is perfectly normal in English. [This construction is frequently used for the similar phrase "warrior monk tradition"](https://www.google.ca/#q=%22warrior+monk+tradition%22).

If 'Saint Poet' isn't a recognized term, then you are talking about a tradition that has attributes both of poetry and saintliness. In that case use the adjectival form of both words. Call it the '**saintly poetic tradition**'. No need for the hyphen in this case.